# Eclipse Plugin Development: Custom intro screen doesnt works on deployed version

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have created a custom plugin which replaces the existing welcome page(Intro page) to the page I wanted. I used the below link to make it work on eclipse run configuration:-
https://help.eclipse.org/neon/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/ua_intro_minimal.htm?cp=2_0_19_0_1_2

I had to edit the plugin.xml of Eclipse SDK to make it work. Below are the steps:-

```
    <extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.intro">
      <introProductBinding
            introId="org.eclipse.ui.intro.universal"
            productId="org.eclipse.sdk.ide">
      </introProductBinding>
</extension>

// Change the introId to "org.eclipse.intro.minimal" so that the extension code looks like this.

<extension
        point="org.eclipse.ui.intro">
      <introProductBinding
            introId="org.eclipse.intro.minimal"
            productId="org.eclipse.sdk.ide">
      </introProductBinding>
    </extension>
```

The above configuration works well when I am running the plugin as project. However when I try to export the plugin as jar file and import in Eclipse SDK then the default welcome page is shown on load. Theres no way I found where I can specify to pick the Intro screen from the new plugin added.

Does any user faced the similiar issue?

Comment: A plugin should not be trying to replace the Welcome screen - that belongs to the product. It should just add an entry to the existing page.

Comment: I wanted it for my custom usage. And since development environment allows it, so I thought it means it should work for deployed version.

Comment: And what would happen if the user installed two plugins which tried to do this? Which would 'win'? The correct way to change the welcome is to build a new RCP with a different product declaration (the rest of the RCP can be the normal plugins).

Comment: I wanted to make the plugin for my own personal use. I wont be publishing the plugin anywhere so the question of adding a new plugin to alter the intro page doesnt arise. Can you please provide me the link to the new RCP with a different product declaration?